# Socket programming - broadcast with net mask class B

Tags: sockets, broadcast, netmask

I have a problem with broadcasting data when I'm using class B of netmask.
For example I have 3 PC's with these configs:

PC1: 
  IP Address: 192.168.1.10
  Netmask: 255.255.0.0

PC2:
  IP Address: 192.168.1.11
  Netmask: 255.255.0.0

PC3:
  IP Address: 192.168.2.5
  Netmask: 255.255.0.0

I want to send a broadcast packet from PC1 to PC's in range 1 only (PC2 in this example).
But as I found I should use 192.168.255.255 as broadcast address that sends the packet to PC2 and PC3 together. I can't use something like 192.168.1.255 to send the packet to PC2 only.
Is there any way to send packet to range 1 only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give more details for the purpose of what you are attempting?

Comment: It's simple. I just want to send some packets for example to 192.168.1.X only. this packet should not receive by 192.168.2.X PC's.

Answer (score 0):

Network wise all the machines are in the same subnet (range). Thus the broadcast will always target all nodes on this subnet. Depending on what you are doing i suggest:

- Use multicast
- Teach your receiving nodes to ignore packets that are not intended for them

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About your suggestions there's some problems. about second choice I should say that it will cause broadcast storm. about first one as I know it will cause storm too (about this one I'm not sure if there's a way to prevent it)

Comment: Your machines are all on the same subnet. If you use broadcast in that setup you *will* target all machines in the subnet. It's simply how a broadcast works. You could change your network setup but then you need a router between the subnets. If you want to prevent the storm you shouldn't use broadcast. I'm not sure if you actually need BC. Send a broadcast - make the targeted clients respond. Use the responses to address the clients directly.